# How do I access these functions from DefinitelyTyped in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, definitelytyped

I am trying to create an Angular2 app that works with money amounts.  I am trying to use [dinero.js](https://dinerojs.com/index.html) to represent money values, but I am having a hard time using certain features in Typescript.

As the instructions suggested, I installed the DefinitelyTyped mappings for dinero.js using this command

```
npm install @types/dinero.js --save
```

The type mappings for this library are declared [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cbb0c91fca47270d9e0c098db7318b35b08a9725/types/dinero.js/index.d.ts).

I import the library into my code like this:

```
import * as Dinero from 'dinero.js';
```

This allows me to use the factory function `Dinero`.  The problem is, that declaration lists some functions (namely `maximum` and `minimum`) that I want to use, but can't seem to get to.

If I try `Dinero.maximum(...)`, I get:

```
"export 'maximum' (imported as 'Dinero') was not found in 'dinero.js'
```

If I try to import those functions directly:

```
import {maximum, minimum} from 'dinero.js';
```

and call by `maximum(...)`, I get:

```
"export 'minimum' was not found in 'dinero.js'
```

How do I actually get to these functions?

Comment: You have to import `Dinero` like this `import Dinero from 'dinero.js'`

Comment: When I do that, my IDE yells at me saying `This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.`  Is enabling this bad practice or is it fine? If it's fine, why is it disabled by default?

Comment: Either way, I tried enabling that flag, and now I am getting this error:
`core.js:6260 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: dinero_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

you need to install these first :

```
npm install dinero.js --save

npm install @types/dinero.js --save
```

and then import and use it like this :

```
import  Dinero from "dinero.js";

const some_currency: Dinery.Currency = 'USD'
const some_val: Dinero.Dinero = Dinero({amount: 0, currency: some_currency})
```

this is the stackblitz url which is working :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-spxp5x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thsi stackblitz contains your solution , please have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-spxp5x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts